# Error trying to register game achievement: The given selector string \"game:points\" is invalid

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I keep trying to register a Facebook game achievement (having successfully registered two others previously for the same app), but I am now getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The given selector string \"game:points\" is invalid for Ent with ID 10150677676736030.", 
    "type": "OGPropertySelectorInvalidException"
  }
 }
```

Has anyone else run into this problem or perhaps know what might be causing this? Like I said I was able to register two other achievements before this for the same app.

Comment: Did you change the object type for your app? When I look up the provided ID in the Graph Explorer tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150677676736030), it reports back as a 'website', so the game:x actions won't be valid.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I changed the name of a custom object I was using.  You need to delete all the old posts you made with that object.  The easiest way to do it is to remove the app from your facebook account and check the box that says "delete all activity".